# iMessages app is missing after update of OSX to Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, messages

I have updated my Mac Mini to Mountain Lion.

I had iMessages beta installed on OSX Lion but after upgrading it's disappeared and now I don't have any iMessages.

I checked various sources for it with no luck. I also tried to reinstall the beta, but wasn't able to do that, either.

Comment: As Jonathan said, they retitled the app to "Messages" when they went from beta. As well, they deprecated the beta with the release of the final product, so that's why you're unable to install it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The chat tool which supports iMessage in Mountain Lion is called Messages.  Try searching for "Messages" in Spotlight, and loading the application.

Comment: Just tried no luck, it cant even find the .app file i'm bit confused where did it go after update?

Comment: If you've just upgraded your machine, try installing all of the latest updates.  "Messages" should certainly be there.

Comment: Jonathan just tried again no luck i have no idea why it just disappeared!

Comment: I would contact Apple support.  This sounds like a problem directly caused by the installation of Mountain Lion.

Comment: Jonathan do you have a URL for that? cant seem to find on support site of UK

Comment: The UK support site is available here: http://www.apple.com/uk/support/contact/.  I don't think there is a specific line to call on for installation issues, but the main support options will, hopefully, be able to help.

Comment: Since you been helpful i will accept as answer - however i managed to FIX the problem by re-installing the mountain lion and messages app is there now and works.